# Control not getting focus in Narrator Touch Navigation

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a UserControl that I create a CustomAutomationPeer for.

While tabbing through the app this control gets focus and does the right thing.
However, when I tried swyping the control was skipped over.

I tried setting the IsContent and IsControl properties to true, and also overriding the Get calls in the AutomationPeer to true also and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't able to solve this exact issue, however I learned that all the Text items are suppose to get focus in touch navigation. I was trying to make touch focus in the same order as keyboard navigation (which is a NO!).

You are able to add items to the RAW accessibility view, which will basically remove them from getting any type of focus. I found this useful mainly with buttons whose content was an image or glyph in order to remove double focus, however I'm sure there are a handful of other uses.